# loading files by criteria in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have searched for some ways to load xyz files (a table with numbers) from a molecular database but can not get the code to work perfectly as I want it.

If the compare matrix is =0 open all files, if it is of size 1,1 but different to 0, compare all files to the one inside `compare` and finally if the size is >1,1 the files are specified and it works.

Also the files are named with digits and it would be nice to be able to open them without renaming.

If I remember my matlab is 2016, I don't code often, that is why I mess up syntax and would like to make it work easy for a long run of compares. If anyone knows how to open an online database of xyz files, it would be even better.

```
cd input
compare=['a2';'s4'];
cd ..
NumMols=size(compare);
if compare = 0
  compare = dir;
  compare = compare(~[compare.isdir]);
  NumMols=size(compare);
else if size(compare)=(1,1)
  FileNrOne=compare
  compare = dir;
  compare = compare(~[compare.isdir]);
  compare = compare(~[FileNrOne]);
  NumMols=size(compare)+1;
end

for k=1:NumMols
  cd input
  mol = dlmread(compare(k),'\t');
  cd ..
end
```

Edit1:
I am adding the code that I use since one comment is asking for some code I already run and works. I also need to rename files so that no numbers are in the filename.

```
cd input
compare=['a';'s'];
cd ..
NumMols=size(compare);
for k=1:NumMols
  cd input
  mol = dlmread(compare(k),'\t');
  cd ..
%some comparisons
end
%more comparisons
```

Comment: `if size(compare)=(1,1)` this is invalid syntax

Comment: If you’re going to post code, at least run it first to make sure it’s correct. Being rusty is no excuse for syntax errors.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have added working code and I admit I am not testing problems like "=", but please let me know where I can find the solutions to the other problems. The working code is good enough for me but others might have trouble using it since it could be used for more than I intend to. Making it more automated would encourage others to use it for better things.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect `compare=['a';'s']` to do and where you think the value `NumMols` is coming from?

Comment: @nekomatic `compare` has the filenames of the molecules that I will compare and `NumMols` is the number of files that the iteration is going to need to go through all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it your question is that you want to take a list of filenames that contains either zero, one or more than one items and you want to take different actions in each case. Among the actions you want to take is to read the names of the files in a specific directory and compare them to a filename from your original list.

The first problem I see with your code is that you're specifying your list as a character array:

```
compare=['a';'s'];
```

This may give you problems when it comes to comparing, as each filename will get padded with spaces to make it the same length as the longest one. Use a **cell array of strings** instead. To check how many items are in this array, use `length`.

Next you want to get the contents of a directory:

```
compare = dir;
compare = compare(~[compare.isdir]);
```

That's OK and gives you a struct array with details of all the files but not the directories. But this

```
compare = compare(~[FileNrOne]);
```

is meaningless because as far as I can see `FileNrOne` is supposed to be a character array, and `~['some character array']` just returns a logical array the length of the character array with all elements false. If you have a struct array from `dir` - let's call it `dirResult` - and you want to remove the element whose name is `removeMe`, do:

```
dirResult = dirResult(~strcmpi(removeMe, {dir.name}));
```

Use `strcmpi` if your file system is case-insensitive (Windows, Mac usually) or `strcmp` if it's case-sensitive (Linux).

If this answer doesn't enable you to fix your problem, please update your question with more detail of exactly what is going wrong, or ask a new and more specific question.

Comment: thank you, I will think about these things, since I didn't yet

Answer (score 0):

Since I find it hard to read answers for other questions, I thought it would be nice to add an answer that explains what I learned. Also I might have learned something wrong and someone might correct me here.

First the cell array of strings in `compare` is needed in the case that files are given and `iscell` checks for that afterwords.

```
compare = {'s444173xyz.txt','a2345345xyz.txt'}; %or compare =0;
NumMols = size(compare);
tf = iscell(compare);
if tf == 0
 if compare == 0
  compare = dir('input');
  compare = compare(~[compare.isdir]);
  NumMols=size(compare);
 end
else
 if tf == 1
  if NumMols == 1
   FileNrOne=compare
   compare = dir;
   compare = compare(~[compare.isdir]);
   compare = compare(~[FileNrOne]);
   NumMols=size(compare)+1;
  end
 end
end

for k=1:NumMols
  cd input
  if tf == 1
    mol = dlmread(char(compare(k)),'\t');
  else
    mol = dlmread(compare(k).name,'\t');
  end
  cd ..
end
```

I need to work on `compare = compare(~[FileNrOne]);` since it gives rise to other questions where comparisons really become useful